# Problems with reassembling Bosch POF 1200 AE router

Tags: tools, powertools, routers

So in my infinite wisdom, while removing one of the springs from my  Bosch POF 1200  AE router I accidentally took the router motor out of the housing itself.

When I removed it I heard *click*, *click* and thought nothing of it until I tried to reinstall the motor into the housing, and after a bit of investigation it looks like there's some... brushes or something blocking the top bearing going all the way in.

[image]

From the pictures I took and from the online instructional diagram it seems that they sit in the brass-looking areas either side, however my fingers and pliers aren't long enough to get in there and reseat them.

I did manage to use a pencil to navigte and one into the brass seat, but there is some sort of spring mechanism that forces it out; I'm asssuming this to make these brush-things contact the router motor to make it run *shrugs*.

[image]

Can anybody help me make sense of this and how to fix it such that I can successfully reassemble my router?

Answer (score 1):

I usually find a way to hold the brushes back in the holder against the spring pressure.

Either a wire loop tying each brush back or some brush holders have holes to insert a pin through - there can be many options to consider, but there has to be a method to assemble it.

Once the armature is back in position then remember to release the brushes.

Comment: Ah, thank for the advice! After getting annoyed at it, I unscrewed the tiedowns on the top foor the brass pieces and extracted them from the situation, got the motor reseated and fastened in, then I inserted the graphite brushes into the brass housing and then fenagled them back into place and screwed them back down. AND IT FIRES UP! HOORAH!